# Manager IP & BlockStorage configuratio Openstack

Tags: cloudify

I have a question with CLoudify 2.7:

How do I (if possible of course :) ) force Cloudify to give a specific IP to the manager when bootstraping a cloud?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cloud drivers provided with Cloudify out of the box do not include an option to set a specific IP during bootstrapping. That said, the cloud drivers are pluggable and designed for extensibility, so it should be easy to add this functionality to the existing cloud drivers.

It is also worth mentioning that you can extend the built-in cloud drivers (or create new ones) using Groovy. This is often easier to do for small project as it does not require a compile cycle, just place the Groovy file with the Cloud driver implementation in the lib directory of the Cloud configuration directory. See "Tweaking an existing cloud driver" here: http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/clouddrivers/developing_custom_clouddriver.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think I'll go for extending the driver with a groovy file :)

Comment: Cool. Please keep in mind that Cloudify 2.x is nearing end of life. You may want to check out Cloudify 3.